# How to write a test case for module dependent function using EXPECT_CALL in Google test?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am new to google test environment. I have a sample code written in C and want to perform unit test with Google test framework.

Below is the sample code

```
// My module function (test.c)

void Update_user_value(void)
{
    int user_value;
    user_value = get_val_module(); /* return a integer value*/

    if(user_value == 0x1)
      update_user_flag(true);
    else
      update_user_flag(false);  
}

// This function is in the other module(stub.c) , so we can use Mock function

void update_user_flag(bool val)
{
    struct *temp;

    if(val == true)
    {
        temp->userflag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->userflag = 0;
    }
}
```

I wan to write a test case for the `Update_user_value` function (only for `test.c`). Through this function, i am sending some flag value to other module (`update_user_flag`) to set the flag.

I have written a simple google test like this

```
    TEST_F(sampletest, setuser_flag_true_testcase)
    {
        //Get value from module
        ON_CALL(*ptr1, get_val_module()).WillByDefault(Return(0x1)); //Mock function
    
        EXPECT_CALL(*ptr2, get_val_module(_)).Times(1); // Mock function

        Update_user_value();
    }

    TEST_F(sampletest, setuser_flag_false_testcase)
    {
        //Get value from module
        ON_CALL(*ptr1, get_val_module()).WillByDefault(Return(0x0)); //Mock function
    
        EXPECT_CALL(*ptr2, get_val_module(_)).Times(1); // Mock function

        Update_user_value();
    }
```

My question: Is this test case is enough to validate the `Update_user_value` function ?
Also i want to know, `EXPECT_CALL()` is good to use for setting a value to other module ?
If my understanding is wrong, please suggest me a better test case ?

Answer (score 0):

`ON_CALL`, `EXPECT_CALL` are macros designed to be used on mock objects. Usually the use case is as follows:

1. You create an interface to derive from (it will be mocked in your test).
2. You pass the mock object (to method or via dependency injection).
3. You make expectations on this *object*.

See example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;

    virtual int bar() = 0;
};

class FooMock : public Foo {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(bar, int());
};

bool check_bar_over_42(Foo& foo) {
    if (foo.bar() > 42) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

TEST(check_bar_over_42_test, bar_below_42) {
    FooMock fooMock{};

    EXPECT_CALL(fooMock, bar()).WillOnce(testing::Return(41));

    ASSERT_FALSE(check_bar_over_42(fooMock));
}

TEST(check_bar_over_42_test, bar_above_42) {
    FooMock fooMock{};

    EXPECT_CALL(fooMock, bar()).WillOnce(testing::Return(43));

    ASSERT_TRUE(check_bar_over_42(fooMock));
}
```

AFAIK there is no way of using `EXPECT_CALL`s on C-like functions. One approach for your problem would be link-time mocking: given a method `get_val_module` is defined in a separate library, you can create test-only library with `get_val_module` that will allow you to return the expected values. In tests you would link against test lib, in production - against the real lib.